# Params sql false

Tags: mysql, delphi-7, rad

i tried this code

```
source := 'prénom';
FDQuery4.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO  name(:pSource) Values ("kkkkk")');
FDQuery4.Params.ParamByName('pSource').Value := source;
FDQuery4.execSQL;
```

but it shows me this exception.

> Exception 'first chance' à $75B2845D. Classe d'exception
>   EMySQLNativeException avec un message '[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''prénom')
>   Values ("kkkkk")' at line 1'.

i don't understand why prénom is read like this ''prénom')

Comment: You cannot use a parameter for a column name, they are for values only.  Construct the string manually by appending `\`prénom\``

Comment: @Alex , FireDAC contains macro support for "parametrized" column names.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use parameters for field names.
Construct the query before executing like this

```
source := 'prénom';
FDQuery4.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO  name(' + source + ') Values ("kkkkk")');
FDQuery4.execSQL;
```

And better is to use parameters for your value

```
source := 'prénom';
FDQuery4.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO  name(' + source + ') Values (:pValue)');
FDQuery4.Params.ParamByName('pValue').Value := 'kkkk';
FDQuery4.execSQL;
```

As suggested by Victoria you can also do it like this when using FireDAC:
**This does solves your first problem.**

```
FDQuery4.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO name (&TheColumn) VALUES ("TheValue")');     
FDQuery4.MacroByName('TheColumn').AsIdentifier := 'prénom';
```

Comment: Better create macro for parametrized column name (FireDAC). In code they are used in a similar way as parameters. You can write `FDQuery4.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO name (&TheColumn) VALUES ("TheValue")'); FDQuery4.MacroByName('TheColumn').AsIdentifier := 'prénom';`

Comment: @Victoria Added it to my answer